# Database creation fails - Flask - Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am following along on a tutorial on YouTube for Flask and Postgres. At the point where I have to create a database I went into Python and used command `from app import db` which executed fine. But the command `db.create_all()` is giving me the following error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I have checked and my password is correct.

I have scanned through the many answeres on StackOverflow, all of which suggest password being incorrect. Maybe I missed some. I am still going through the documentation and other posts on stack overflow but any pointers would be appreciated.

```
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:mypassword@localhost/lexus'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Figured out what the issues was. When I created the database in pdAdmin4 by default it allows `-1` connections. I changed it to 2 or any suitable number as per your requirement. This worked.